# wrong with CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER in setting.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

**setting.py**

```
# celery

CELERY_TIMEZONE = "UTC"
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["application/json"]
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"

# celery-beat

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django-celery-beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
    "corsheaders",
    "celery",
    "django_celery_results",
    "django_celery_beat",
    # Custom apps
    ...
]
```

So I want to run my celery-beat:
**celery -A config beat -l INFO**
where config is my project's name

And than I have error message:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django-celery-beat'**

**Celery.py**

````
    "clear_spent_in_categories_every_month": {
        "task": "category.tasks.clear_all_spent",
        # "schedule": crontab(day_of_month="1", hour="0", minute="0")
        "schedule": crontab(hour="4", minute="40")
    }
}```

I tried to restart my IDE, server, reinstall celery, checked my INSTALLED_APPS, and I don't know, why it doesn't work. But if I delete setting CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django-celery-beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler", it's works with celery.beat.PersistentScheduler
````

Comment: [Install it](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/)?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with underscores instead of hyphens:
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = "django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler"